Can't drop role because it has privileges that are not revoked even when REVOKE statement is successful
I can't drop a role from a postgres database. Running the DROP ROLE statement outputs the following error:
DROP ROLE read_only;


SQL Error [2BP01]: ERROR: role "read_only" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
  Detail: privileges for table orgs.client

When I try to revoke those privileges from the tables, the REVOKE statement is successful (no errors at all):
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE orgs.client FROM read_only;

But then, if I try to drop the role again, I get the same error above.
I have no idea why the REVOKE statement is not working as expected. Or maybe it is working but the issue is something else. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Output of \z orgs.client:
                                                           Access privileges
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |                                Access privileges                                | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+--------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+----------
 orgs   | client | table | "prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED"=arwdDxt/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"         +|                   | 
        |        |       | REDACTED_dev=arwdDxt/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"                       +|                   | 
        |        |       | landlord=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"                    +|                   | 
        |        |       | read_only=r/landlord                                                           +|                   | 
        |        |       | read_write=arwd/landlord                                                       +|                   | 
        |        |       | landlord=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/costa                                                  +|                   | 
        |        |       | landlord=arwdDxt/landlord                                                      +|                   | 
        |        |       | REDACTED_read_only=r/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"                       +|                   | 
        |        |       | REDACTED_read_write=arwdD/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"                  +|                   | 
        |        |       | REDACTED_admin=arwdDxt/"prisma-beta-gsa@REDACTED-beta.iam"                      |                   | 



NOTE: I'm working with a postgres 11 hosted in a Google Cloud SQL Instance. Because of this, I have no access to a superuser role. I do have access to the postgres user that is the closest you can get to a superuser (docs).

Please connect with psql and show the result of \z orgs.client.

Done! I've redacted some parts of some role names.

The REVOKE must be issued by landlord.

Ok. I think I know where this is going. I tried to remove the read_only permission (this time running the REVOKE statement as the role who granted it, i.e. landlord) and then the permission was finally revoked. @LaurenzAlbe If you post an answer I can mark the question as answered!

Since the privilege was granted by user landlord, you should also use that role to revoke the privilege:
REVOKE SELECT ON orgs.client FROM read_only;


Always Remember that privileges are "cummulatives" due to inheritance that means that a privilege done by user A and user B must be revoked by user A and alos by user B. The most appropriate view to see these meatadata is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES_PRIVILEGES... \z does not give appropiate velues for these. Always use queries !
